# How to present the function by the Fourier integral?

Tags: definite-integrals, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

I have a function $f(x) = \log(4+x^2)-2\log(x)$ defined on the interval $[0; \infty)$
I should to present it by the Fourier integral continuing it evenly on the interval $(-\infty;0]$ in this form:
$$\int_0^\infty[a(z)\cos zx+b(z)\sin zx]dx$$
I continued it in an even way and got the following schedule[image]

The function is even so $b(z) = 0$
But I can`t find a(z). My teacher said that I should find it using inverse Fourier transformation. Can you help me,please?

Comment: The word for "график" in this context is "graph" or "plot", not "schedule" :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have $$f(x)=\log \left(1+\frac{4}{x^2} \right)$$

I will use the exponential form of Fourier transform:

$$\hat{f}(\omega)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x) e^{-2 \pi i \omega x} dx$$

Because the function is even, the sign of the imaginary part doesn't really matter.

As the OP says, it is correct to write:

$$\hat{f}(\omega)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x) \cos (2 \pi \omega x) dx$$

So we need to find:

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \log \left(1+\frac{4}{x^2} \right) \cos (2 \pi \omega x) dx$$

Mathematica takes this integral and gives:

$$\hat{f}(\omega)=\frac{1-e^{-4 \pi | \omega|}}{| \omega|}$$

It's almost an (even) hyperbolic function, slightly modified by the vanishing exponential term, so it is finite at $0$. $\hat{f}(0)=4 \pi$.

[image]

If we don't want to use the angular frequency, we can change it to:

$$2 \pi \omega=z$$

$$\hat{f}(z)=2 \pi \frac{1-e^{-2 | z|}}{| z|}$$

---

**Update:**

The inverse transform is easy to prove by https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frullani_integral, using the exponential inverse Fourier transform.

**Update 2:**

The original integral can also be found, if we use the Feinman's trick:

$$I(a)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty \log \left(1+\frac{a^2}{x^2} \right) \cos (2 \pi \omega x) dx$$

$$\frac{d}{da}I(a)=2a\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\cos (2 \pi \omega x)}{a^2+x^2 }  dx=2\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\cos (2 \pi \omega a x)}{1+x^2 }  dx=2 \pi e^{-2 \pi |\omega a|}$$

Now we integrate w.r.t. $a$:

$$I(a)=-\frac{1}{|\omega|} e^{-2 \pi |\omega a|} +\frac{1}{|\omega|}$$

Where the constant of integration was determined by the original integral (it's not that obvious, but I will leave the discussion out).

Finally we set $a=2$ and obtain:

$$I(2)=\frac{1-e^{-4 \pi |\omega |}}{|\omega|}  $$

Comment: I'd say $f(x)=\log(1+a^2/x^2) =h(x+a)+h(x-a)-2h(x),h(x) =  \log|x|$ and $-2i \pi x \partial_x h =-2i\pi $ so that $\partial_\xi (2i \pi \xi \hat{h}) = -2i \pi \delta, \hat{h} = -\frac{1}{2|\xi|}$ and $\hat{f} = (e^{2i \pi a\xi}+e^{-2i \pi a\xi}-2) \hat{h}$

Comment: Thank you! It helps me so much. But i don't understand the way you follow from 2*a*integral(cos(2pi*ω*x)/(a^2+x^2)dx) to 2*integral(cos(2pi*ω*a*x)/(1+x^2)dx) Also i can't make sure that  the constant of integration is -1

Comment: @PashaMinigun, I have simply changed the variable $x \to ay$, but kept the same letter $y \to x$. And as for the constant, not sure how to justify it, maybe consider the asymptotic behavior for $a \ll 1$, since we can't simply substitute $a=0$ as the integral would diverge